# Help with solving 3 simultaneous sine equations.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Is it even possible to solve $3$ sine equations with $3$ unknowns? I tried to do so, but i always reach a dead end. For example, i have these $3$ equations that I am stuck on:

$2.3 = \sin(2.93a-b)+c$

$1.91 = \sin(3.55a-b)+c$

$1.99 = \sin(3.93a-b)+c$

I've tried subtracting equation $1$ from equation $2$, and then applying various trig rules. However, I didn't solve much
[this is what I've tried to do so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0jJk.jpg)

If it is not possible to solve a sine system of equations, why is that so?

Comment: You could try numerical methods, I'm not sure there's a clean solution.

Comment: The factors of $a$ represent different frequency terms, and trying to match values on waveforms of different frequencies is a notoriously tricky problem.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, let us observe that

$$\text{if} \ (a,b,c) \  \text{is a solution, then} \ \begin{cases} 
(a,b+2p\pi,c)\\(-a,-b+(2q+1)\pi,c)\end{cases} \ \text{are solutions as well} \tag{1}$$

for any $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

- Second point : variable $c$ can be eliminated by subtraction in this way :

$$\begin{cases}2.3 &=& \sin(2.93a-b)+c\\
1.91 &=& \sin(3.55a-b)+c\\
1.99 &=& \sin(3.93a-b)+c\end{cases} \implies \begin{cases}\sin(2.93a-b)-\sin(3.55a-b)-0.39&=&0& (Eq. i)\\
\sin(3.93a-b)-\sin(3.55a-b)-0.08&=&0&(Eq. ii)\end{cases}$$

(a 2-variables problem is much simpler to solve...)

- Third point : we are in a case where (numerical) Newton-Raphson method can be fruitfully applied. You will find a description of this method in an answer of mine to a recent question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4769066/305862).
  Using it (see Matlab program below), I have found what I would call a fundamental solution

$$(a,b,c)\approx(1.333855072239,0.116009111999,2.905658851511)\tag{2}$$

with an infinity of other "cousin" solutions deduced from this one through one of the two transformations given in (1).

Here is a graphical representation of the very intricated curves defined by equations (Eq. i) and (Eq. ii) in the plane with coordinates $(a,b)$. Intersections of red and blue curves give the roots (some of them, all "cousins" of solution given by (2), have been materialized).

[image]

One can guess on this graphical representations other solutions, for example this one :

$$(a,b,c)\approx(5.963166188745,4.979302298302,2.37352956047)\tag{3}$$

Matlab program :

> ```
> h=0.000001; % small increment
> format long;
> fa=@(a,b)(sin(2.93*a-b)-sin(3.55*a-b)-0.39); % difference between 1st and 2nd equation
> fb=@(a,b)(sin(3.93*a-b)-sin(3.55*a-b)-0.08); % same thing with 2nd and third.
> V=rand(2,1); % random initialization
> for k=1:20
>    a=V(1);b=V(2);
>    J1=[fa(a,b),fa(a,b)
>        fb(a,b),fb(a,b)];
>    J2=[fa(a+h,b),fa(a,b+h)
>        fb(a+h,b),fb(a,b+h)];
>    J=(J2-J1)/h; % approx. Jacobian
>    V=V-inv(J)*[fa(a,b),fb(a,b)]', % Newton-Raphson step
> end;
> [fa(a,b),fb(a,b)], % sanity check : should be very close to [0,0]
> [2.3-sin(2.93*a-b),1.91-sin(3.55*a-b),1.99-sin(3.93*a-b)],  % values of c
> ```

Comment: Just added a figure (and slightly changed the program). Any comment ?

Comment: This figure shows that, unless you restrict $a,b,c$ to a certain range ($(-\pi,\pi)$ for example), it is doubtful that you can express all solutions in a compact way.

Answer (score 0):

It bothers me that there is no coefficient multiplying the $\sin()$ terms. In terms of curve fitting, you need those factors.

I will demonstrate in solving a related equation for three points $(x_i,y_i)$ and $i=1\ldots3$

$$ y_i = c +  r \sin\left( x_i - b \right) $$

This assumes $a=1$ and then introduces a new coefficient $r$ in front of the $\sin()$ function.

The above equation can be expressed as as system of equations

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \sin(x_1) & \cos(x_1) \\
1 & \sin(x_2) & \cos(x_2) \\
1 & \sin(x_3) & \cos(x_3) \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
c \\ r \cos(b) \\ -r \sin(b) 
\end{bmatrix} $$

as the expansion of the above $y_i = c + r \cos(b) \sin(x_i) - r \sin(b) \cos(x_i)$ is applied to the three points.

The solution for the given points is evaluated using the Vandermode matrix method below:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
c \\ r \cos(b) \\ -r \sin(b) 
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \sin(1.93) & \cos(1.93) \\
1 & \sin(3.55) & \cos(3.55) \\
1 & \sin(3.93) & \cos(3.93) \\ 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} 
\begin{bmatrix}
2.3 \\ 1.91 \\ 1.99 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
2.397740934545856 \\ 0.08185188456904127 \\ 0.4960298267574926
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with
$$\boxed{c = 2.397740934545856}$$
$$\boxed{r = \sqrt{0.08185188456904127^2 + 0.4960298267574926^2}  = 0.5027378243583545}$$
and
$$\boxed{b = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{-0.4960298267574926}{0.08185188456904127} \right) = -1.407256042281151}$$

and graph

[image: chart]

Comment: Introducing this unknown $r$ changes the nature of the question.

Comment: @JeanMarie - yes, and it makes it solvable. Any fit is useless without an underlying model and it is up to the _op_ to decide the course of action.